# Count how many times a value occurs across tables

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, group-by, count

First post here! Really need some help.

I have a table with buildings. In this table, there is a number of attributes, of which I am interested in 2:

```
- roof_material
- additional_roof_material
```

In the column roof material, there is 10 different roof materials, with the numbers 1-10.

The same type of additional roof materials are listed in additional_roof_material.

How do I count how many times buildings with roof_material 1, has an additional_roof_material 1, for an instance?

This is what i want to do, just for every material:

```
Select count(*)
From dbo.40000t where roof_material = 1 and additional_roof_material = 1
```

I want to do it for each of the types, so i get a complete comparision of how many times roof_material 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 has additional_roof_material 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

Comment: can you provide an example? Write a table and the expected result, please.

Comment: You have tagged this question as both mysql and postgresql - could you clarify which database language is in use please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get permutation counts from a table using `sum()` with a case statement

```
select
    sum((case when roof_material = 1 and additional_roof_material = 1 then 1 else 0 end)) as material_1_1,
    sum((case when roof_material = 2 and additional_roof_material = 2 then 1 else 0 end)) as material_2_2
    -- etc...
from
    dbo.40000t
```

This query has an implicit `group by` clause - because I am only selecting aggregates I do not need to explicitly specify a `group by`.

---

**Update**

As requested in a comment, if you want each permutation as a distinct record

```
select
    roof_material,
    additional_roof_material,
    count(1) as num_instances
from
    dbo.40000t
-- Not sure if you want permutations where roof_material != additional_roof_material or not.
-- Uncomment these next 2 lines if you do not want those permutations
--where
--  roof_material = additional_roof_material
group by
    roof_material,
    additional_roof_material
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this will work perfectly. I just realized that the data type is text, will it cause any problems if I cast as int, inside the sum()?

Comment: Actually, it only returns: 1 for material_1_1 and 2 for material_2_2.... Is the cast function causing problems maybe?

Comment: You can cast the columns to int or just wrap the numbers in quotes `when roof_material = '1'` - either will work.

Comment: is it possible to have them listed in a new row, when i start counting material 2?